# User and object foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make User based instances for blog posts but all my tries keep showing all the posts for every user. For example, I make a new post and publish it. All the posts show up for every user instead of only the user that is logged in.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('myblog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
            form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('myblog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_publish_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_publish_list.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_publish_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'myblog/post_publish_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('myblog.views.post_list')

def post_delete(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('myblog.views.post_list')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter out `Post`s where `author` is the current user.

Replace:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
```

with:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user,
                            published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
```