# Filtering by User Foreign Key and Admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

The solution on post [User and object foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474874/user-and-object-foreign-key) helped answer the first part of my challenge but how do I use this solution and still see all Posts when logged in as an Admin User?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: If you are going to down vote with anonymity, please place a comment so those of us wondering can understand why.  I am assuming you didn't want me to completely copy another SO post to add to my question....

Comment: The answer to your question surely is "by not doing that filter when the user is admin". What are you actually asking?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need, but can't figure out the filter syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the condition that if the requested user is admin, you can dispaly all the posts to him else display the requested user posts by the following code snippet

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
   posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
else:
   posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user,
                        published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
```

or for more simplicity

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')

if not request.user.is_superuser:
    posts = posts.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed...I was missing the whole is_superuser part of the syntax.